# Posting extra answer to support existing answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Here's the situation:

- A question has answer A which explains something fairly well
- I already have an answer there with alternative solution B
- However, I see that A can be explained in more detail and on deeper level that A already provides.  Such explanation is unrelated to B,  so doesn't seem appropriate to edit into my existing answer and would be too long for a comment under A

Would it be appropriate to post a new answer C ?

Comment: Probably. In some circumstances you may consider editing A instead. Depends.

Comment: @Zanna In this case, it'd be like a couple paragraphs and manual references added, so it's an edit that'd change the answer significantly, that's why I think it'd be more suitable as separate post

Comment: You might consider linking to the post in question. Even if you're asking about the general principle, sometimes the example helps focus the question. Here it seems to me there are two independent issues; is it ok to post 2 answers to a question (yes, as previous meta posts have shown), and is it ok to post an answer that builds on another answer and explains it in more depth (yeah it's ok, but often you might instead want to comment on the answer suggesting improvements or perhaps edit it to avoid duplication of content)

Comment: It‘s totally fine to change an answer significantly if all you do is extending and improving it (rather than change its meaning or delete content) IMHO. I don‘t see why a new answer would be necessary, but please provide the link.

Comment: I've edited my original answer, specifically https://askubuntu.com/a/704643/295286  It now makes for a longer read, although I tried to separate it into sections